# json array to pandas dataframe and write it to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json array like below and i wanted to convert into a pandas dataframe and write it into a csv finally.

I have a number column from the list as l[0] and i want to add this to the df and write everything into csv.

```
[{'value': ' 5644427289 ', 'page_num': '0', 'score': '0.9', 'coord': '["(Decimal(\'90.000\')", " Decimal(\'257.163\')", " Decimal(\'362.250\')", " Decimal(\'307.683\'))"]', 'height': '50.51999999999998', 'width': '272.25'}]
```

I wanted to write only value,page_num and score to my df  and also i have additionally one more l[0] to my df and finally write it into csv.

for s in range(len(json_obj)):

```
    op_json='{"value":"' + str(json_obj[s]["value"]) + '","page_num":"' + str(json_obj[s]["page_num"]) + '", "score":"' + str(json_obj[s]["score"]) + '"}'
            print(op_json)
            df =pd.DataFrame(None)
            df = json_normalize(op_json)
            if os.path.exists(r'/data/results/0101/a.csv'):
                df.to_csv(r'/data/results/0101/a.csv',mode='a', index=False, header=False)
            else:
                df.to_csv(r'/data/results/0101/a.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that is not working?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(data).iloc[:, :3].to_csv('file_name.csv', index=False)`?

Comment: @chris,can we also add the l[0] to the df and write it into csv  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [{'value': ' 5644427289 ', 'page_num': '0', 'score': '0.9', 'coord': '["(Decimal(\'90.000\')", " Decimal(\'257.163\')", " Decimal(\'362.250\')", " Decimal(\'307.683\'))"]', 'height': '50.51999999999998', 'width': '272.25'}]

pd.DataFrame(l)[['value', 'page_num', 'score']].to_csv('file.csv',index=False)
          value page_num score
0   5644427289         0   0.9
```

Comment: How to add another value which is coming from the list to this df and write it into csv ?

Comment: thank you. Can you also tell how to add the additional value to this df and write into csv?

Comment: if its coming from the same list then just add that in this `[['value', 'page_num', 'score']]` with comma separation for example `[['value', 'page_num', 'score', 'new_col_name']]`

Comment: Thank you, i added the value to my existing json and i am able to do it.